In Bazel, how to check validity of a provided --action_env value?
In a project built with Bazel I'm using --action_env to manually modify the build environment in order to avoid unwanted cache hits (this is a current workaround for a more sophisticated solution, but for now I'm interested in this question generally).
Currently I'm wrapping bazel run into a shell script which appends --action_env and --host_action_env and also checks the provided value for validity.
I now want to want to move the validity checks into the bazel world, in order to run them every time bazel build gets invoked.
Is there a way to create a rule or function which gets executed every time (or at least  once every time the provided values change) and regardless of the target I want to build?
Something like
BUILD
load("//:check_env.bzl", "check_environment_variables")
check_environment_variables()

check_env.bzl
def _check_environment_variables(ctx):
    my_env = ctx.attr.env_var["MY_ENV"]
    print("provided value for MY_ENV:", my_env)
    if not my_env == "foo":
        fail("MY_ENV must be set to 'foo'")
    return []    

check_environment_variables = rule(
    implementation=_check_environment_variables,
    attrs={},
)

but while Bazel does not complain about this approach, it's check_environment_variables won't be executed neither..

There seems to be a bit more to unpack, but I'll try to gloss over the "unwanted cache" hits hinting at something profoundly wrong and this all probably not heading in the right direction.
As given, without any indication on how it was "run" and what was exactly expected to happen, I can say there is nothing for bazel to do nor is there a way tell it to do anything (like build or run or test), the rule is declared without giving any name to the target. There is no target to populate the graph, and no action for the target could even be requested (from the command line).
If we named it and asked for it, it would actually fail, because there is no env_var attribute to the rule. In fact I am not sure if there is a way to access the environment in this phase. You can use workspace status, you could use (custom) rule (but those would be environmental variables in general, or also --repo_env for the latter). TL;DR if you must, you can (rather crudely):
check_env.bzl:
def _check_environment_variable(ctx):
    output = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.attr.name + ".txt")
    args = ctx.actions.args()
    args.add_all([ctx.attr.var, output])
    ctx.actions.run_shell(
            outputs = [output],
            arguments = [args],
            command = 'echo "${!1}" > "$2"',
            use_default_shell_env = True,
    )
    return [
        DefaultInfo(files = depset([output])),
    ]

check_environment_variables = rule(
    implementation=_check_environment_variable,
    attrs={
        "var": attr.string(mandatory = True),
    },
)  

and BUILD:
load("//:check_env.bzl", "check_environment_variables")
check_environment_variables(
    name = "check_environment_variables",
    var = "MY_ENV",
)

Which then could be checked:
$ MY_ENV=$(date '+%s') bazel build --action_env MY_ENV //:check_environment_variables && { echo ===== ; cat bazel-bin/check_environment_variables.txt ; }
INFO: Analyzed target //:check_environment_variables (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:check_environment_variables up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/check_environment_variables.txt
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.039s, Critical Path: 0.01s
INFO: 2 processes: 1 internal, 1 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 2 total actions
=====
1724173764

But really, if you for instance have a problem with non-deterministic behavior of tools leading to what could constitute "unwanted cache hits"... I'd say channel more energy in resolving the underlying problem rather than trying to neuter one of the greater assets of the build system.

EDIT: You'd always need to (also) build this target to get the file with desired content (such as above a value of given environmental variable) to see effect of --action_env on that target (see what the value for its action was) on a given build.
For instance, if your other ("real") target was //:my_product, you could. Run bazel asking for both targets to be built:
bazel build //:my_product //:check_environment_variables

Or you can group them in a BUILD file as filegroup:
load("//:check_env.bzl", "check_environment_variables")
check_environment_variables(
    name = "check_environment_variables",
    var = "MY_ENV",
)

some_rule(
    name = "my_product",
)

filegroup(
    name = "my_product_and_env_check",
    srcs = [
        ":check_environment_variables",
        ":my_product",
    ],
)

And then build them both with:
bazel build //:my_product_and_env_check


+1 alone for letting be know you suspect a fishy background and still answering my question! And I'm aware I'm doing something very non-bazelesque and working on improving / getting rid of it. Currently I'm configuring a build environment with multiple partly ancient Linux distros and different toolchains involved, which makes it hard to come up with a proper hermetic build. For that reason and because I really need a remote cache, I'm currently injecting a system hash to avoid inter-distro cache hits. But yeah, you don't want this of course..

If I understand this correctly, your snippets declare a target check_environment_variables, which then has to be built explicitly. Is it possible to have this target executed every time, without having to either manually build it or to make every other target depend on it explicitly?

Setting up the build (and toolchains) is not always easy (it's "expensive"), but on the upside it's usually a one time (bigger) cost which is rewarded by easier (cheaper) portability and maintenance...  So worth it. ;) That said, transition phase with intention to fix is a valid approach, just don't get stuck in it because now it "works". ;)
